# How can I say this?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, questions

In this list of phrases, which sounds most natural or most natural and grammatically correct?

- Did anybody saw in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
- Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
- Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which have been hijacked?
- Has anybody seen in this week's news about hijacked plane?
- Has anyone seen the news this week about the matter hijacked plane?

Comment: Not very grammatical, but in spoken English it might be, "Anyone saw that hijacked plane news?" or "Anyone saw that plane hijacking news?"

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don’t know anybody who would say, “Anyone saw …?” It would be, “Anyone see …?”, “Did anyone see …?” (Jay’s answer), “Has anybody seen …?”, or “Who saw the news about the hijacked plane?”

Comment: Strictly speaking, “which was hijacked” is incorrect. It should be “that was hijacked” because you’re using the “was hijacked” phrase to _identify_ the plane that you’re talking about. You would use “which” if you’ve already identified something, and are just providing additional information about it; e.g., “flight 12345, which was hijacked.”

Answer (score 0):

None seem correct to me. I've highlighted the points that seem to be wrong. I'd rephrase it like this: "Has anybody seen this week's news about a hijacked plane?"

> Did anybody **saw** in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
>
> Has anybody seen **in** the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
>
> Has anybody seen **in** the news this week about the plane which **have** been hijacked?
>
> Has anybody seen **in** this week's news about hijacked plane?
>
> Has anyone seen the news this week about the **matter** hijacked plane?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most natural statement would be, "Did anyone see the news this week about the plane that was hijacked?" or "Did anyone see the story about the plane that was hijacked in the news this week?"

In general, I wouldn't say "in the news about ..." because that leaves no subject for the clause. Did you see WHAT in the news? You can "see news about ...", or you can see "a story in the news about ...", or "a plane hijacking in the news". It's common to say either "Have you seen a story in the news about ..." or "Have you seen anything in the news about ...". But it's more concise to just say "Have you seen the news about ..." or "Have you seen any news about ..."

"Did anybody saw in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?" You can't say "did saw". You can say "I did see" or "I saw", but not "I did saw".

"Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?" No subject. You need "Has anybody seen A STORY in the news ..." or some such.

"Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which have been hijacked?" Again, no subject. Also "plane" is singular but "have" is plural. You could say, "Has anybody seen the news this week about the plane which has been hijacked?"

"Has anybody seen in this week's news about hijacked plane?" Again, no subject. And you need an article with "plane", like "the". So, "Has anybody seen this week's news about the hijacked plane?" or "Has anybody seen something in this week's news about the hijacked plane?"

"Has anyone seen the news this week about the matter hijacked plane?" "Matter" and "plane" are both nouns so you can't just stick them together like that. In this case you want to turn "hijacked plane" into a modifier for "matter". The most natural way to do this would be to make it a prepositional phrase. Like, "Has anyone seen the news this week about the matter OF THE hijacked plane?" You could say "... about the hijacked plane matter". That would be grammatically correct, but it sounds awkward to me.

Comment: You could also switch to a gerund:  "Did any of you see that story about the plane hijacking?"

Comment: True. I'm sure there are many other variations, too.